# SQLite Android Query with auto_key increment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a database query that will select the UUID's of my data objects starting at the most recent entry and then continue for a given number.

The query would be something like:

```
SELECT UUID(this is column) FROM tableName WHERE (auto increment)_id <= size(number of entries)
AND _id >= y(offset point) ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT x OFFSET y
```

I'm confused at how to reference the auto key increment and turning this SELECT into public Cursor query() format. Something like

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
      tableName, 
      tableName.Cols.UUID,
      "_id <= size && _id >= y" + " = ?,
      I am unsure,
      null, //groupBy
      null, //having
      _id DESC, //orderBy
      x offset y)
```

Any help please?

Comment: `WHERE (auto increment)_id` Auto increment is a table?

Comment: Edit Suggestion: Post also your Table creation query so that we can check.